# Logging out leaves the display in a garbled state, unable to restart X, or switch to text console

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I have a problem with Ubuntu 12.04. I am running on a Zotac Z68ITX motherboard, which has both a NVidia graphic card GT430 onboard, and a Intel integrated one on chip. I set the PGE/PCIEx option in the BIOS and plugged into the nvidia DVI port to my TV HDMI IN.

The Ubuntu is freshly installed. I also installed the nvidia-current drivers and I can successfully boot and run glxgears. The problem occurs when I log out. Instead of getting back to the lightdm login, I get this "corrupted text"

[image: get this]

After this, the screen goes back to low res, and it blanks to a corrupted blinking cursor. I can't do anything except rebooting. Even ctrl-alt-f1 does not switch to text console. Rebooting is only possible with the off button. It shows more lines of corrupted text as the services are shut down.

Any idea?

**Edit**:
I don't know the reason behind the garbled text, but I was able to get to a console after the event, and starting X manually leads to the following error

```
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Input/output error)
```

I am browsing around, but I haven't settled on a solution yet, mostly because I am doing other things in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this fix: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1066410/comments/44

I had the problem where sometimes my laptop wouldn't load to the login screen, or wouldn't recover from the screensaver. It was basically a race condition, so it was hard to reproduce.

This may not fix it, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I tried all the proposed solutions, but I still get the same problem. Note that the keyboard is also locked. I can't change to console (I'd like to do some debugging, but I can't). Where can I look for logs?

Comment: log files are in /var/log. Some are only viewable by root.

/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log or /var/log/dmesg might be of use.

Comment: I added some more details